# UWP and IMAPI or addressing CD-ROM Drive

Tags: c#, uwp, imapi

I'm pretty certain that IMAPI isn't duplicated in the Universal Windows Platform (which seems like a bit of an oversight) but I need to write audio files to a CD-ROM drive.

Is this even possible?  Where can I find documentation?

Comment: I doubt it's just an oversight. UWP programs are vastly crippled in comparison to real software. And tablets rarely have CDROM drives after all :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no API to write on a CD-ROM drive in UWP.

You could write a [Brokered Windows Runtime Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps) that would allow you to use Win32 APIs to do that, but that would mean the app would no longer be accepted on the Windows Store and would also not work on any other type of device.

Alternatively, you could write a WPF app that would be packaged as UWP app with the [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop).

Comment: what if I were to write a "server" component in Win32 and an interface for it in pure UWP?

Benefit is nice decoupling and the ability to use a tablet to control a machine with an optical disk drive.

Comment: Yes, you can surely do it. It can even be a separate app, or service that communicates with the the uwp app over HTTP for example. But the problem is still that you can't easily put both on Store together